# Javascript - Copying array(by value) into prototype

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was trying to make a constructor function and within it, i had/wanted to place an array:

```
function Animal(s) {
    this.myarr.push(s)
    this.bark = function() {
        console.log(this.myarr)
    }
}

 Animal.prototype = {
    myarr: []
}

var a = new Animal('a');
a.bark()

var b = new Animal('b');
b.bark()
```

The problem is that the array will be passed by reference. The result will be:

```
["a"]
["a", "b"]
```

I then tried Dean Edwards base class:

```
var Animal = Base.extend({
  constructor: function(s) {
    this.some.push(s)
  },
  some: [],

  bark: function() {
    console.log(this.some)
  }
});

var a = new Animal('a');
a.bark()

var b = new Animal('b');
b.bark()
```

The result was the same.

```
["a"]
["a", "b"]
```

I don't know if this is the way arrays should be handler in a javascript 'class' system... though i can re-initialize that property to [] every time i call the constructor.

So, does anyone know how to deal with this? Should i re-initialize the property(if it's an array)?
Thanks in advanced.

Edit:

The problem here is that whenever the constructor is called(this.myarr.push(s) for example) myarr will point to the same array - that's why after a new instance the array will grow in size.

So:

```
var a = new Animal('a')
var b = new Animal('ab')
var c = new Animal('abc')
var d = new Animal('abcd')
```

will result to:

```
["a", "ab", "abc", "abcd"]
```

I want(without defining myarr inside the constructor) myarr to have a default value everytime i call the constructor(through new Animal(()) which should be [ ].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you attach your array to the prototype of the constructor, this array will be available to all instances, so everything an instance does to it, is reflected in `.myarr` in the other instances. If you want an array per instance, you should define it as a 'local' property, i.e. `this.myarr`. What you *can* do is define a method in the prototype that pushes a value into `this.myarr`.

So your constructor function (classes are non extistent in javascript) could look like:

```
function Animal(s) {
    this.myarr = [];
    this.bark = function() {
        console.log(this.myarr)
    }
    this.myarrAdd(s);
}

 Animal.prototype = {
    myarrAdd: function(val){this.myarr.push(val); return this;}
}
```

Comment: i've tried that but the problem is when you want to extend that constructor - you won't have access to this.myarr if it's not defined inside the prototype. Thank anyway.

Comment: i have rushed for the response - you're right. It is a good workaround. But then again, i dont't think it will be copied if Animal will be extended.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. From the code I presented, try extending: `Animal.prototype.barksLoud = function(){ return  this.myarr[0]+' WHOOFF!! '; }`. Works fine and `this.myarr` is available within that Animal.prototype extension method

Comment: I think you should read more on prototypal inheritance, really. Exploring http://javascript.crockford.com would be a good start. By the way: it's *not* a workaround, it's more like standard operating procedure (SOP)

Comment: Yes, you're right. But if you want to copy Animal's prototype along with myarr? It works :d.

Comment: I *still* don't understand what you mean. Try cooking a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net) to show me your intentions.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kTTFM/ - i now see. The Dog constructor inherits myarr. I had this problem when i tried to use a small class system where all the 'attributes' were copied insides the object's prototype(not inside the constructor). Thank you for your time.

Comment: could you tell me what is the difference between myarr defined inside Animal and myarr defined inside Animal.prototype? As far as i can see  there are the same

Comment: It's in the answer: anything you define in the prototype of a constructor is initialized once and available to/mutable by all instances. Anything you define within the constructor (using `this.property`) is local to an instance.